# Como se hace un delete en SLIM

Tags: php, backend, slim, slim3

Quiero eliminar por id las sentencias del back-end en slim v3 y no sé como se realiza...
Tengo la siguientes sentencias por ejemplo un get que hago lo hago de la siguiente manera:

```
$app->get('/obtenerUsuarios', function (Request $request, Response $response, $args) {
    // Para devolverlos todos los usuarios
    $Usuarios = Usuarios::get();

    // mas recomendado usar esta forma
    return sendOkResponse($Usuarios ->toJson(),$response);
});


// Imprimir en formato JSON
function sendOkResponse($message,$response){
    $newResponse = $response->withStatus(200)->withHeader('Content-Type','application/json');
    $newResponse ->getBody()->write($message);
    return $newResponse;
}
```

Asi es como tengo para que eliminara por el id del usuario pero no se que sentencias hay que meterle dentro sin usar bd, del pdo ni esas cosas que no se si se podrá la verdad...

```
$app->delete('/borrarUsuario/{id}', function ($request, $response, $args)       
    // Delete book identified by $args['id']
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$app->delete('/borrarUsuario/{id}', function ($request, $response, $args) {

  $id = $request->getAttribute('id');

  $usuario = Usuarios::find($id);

  $usuario->delete();
});
```

Comment: Aunque esto pueda resolver la pregunta, aqui tratamos de dar respuestas que no sean únicamente un extracto de código. Trata de editar tu respuesta con una pequeña explicación de qué le faltaba al OP y como estas sentencias solucionan el problema. Un saludo y gracias por tu aportación.

Comment: Hola @jdaramburoc, como te comenta el usuario Pikoh, deberías [edit] tu respuesta para añadir algo más de detalle y explicación de lo que hace el código. Lee [answer] y completa el [tour] para más información. Saludos.

Comment: Tienen razón, gracias

Comment: Ya lo siento... pero si supiera como se hacia en su momento no hubiera recurrido a preguntar de esta manera... pero gracias de todos modos ya lo conseguí por mi propia cuenta probando mucho. Pido disculpas.